# Android Error Cancelling event due to no window focus

Tags: android, android-intent

I am learning Android, and trying to make multi screen app to get better at it. I have 3 activities.

```
1) Main
2) Game
3) GameOver
```

Main has game button, when pressed starts intent for the Game Activity. And after timer finishes in Game, I pass score variables to GameOver Activity over intent. 
This flow works fine. But when I press back button after I see results in GameOver activit, the app minimizes. When I unMinimize the app it shows the Main activity screen (which actually want, but without app getting minimized). I am using finish() in Game activity where I am calling intent for GameOver.

In logs, I am getting following errors:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb7d6e128 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb7877690
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=292244107, downTime=292244100, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
```

I created a test app to resolve/understand this issue having 3 activities and same flow. It is working find in that basic activity app. But not in my main app. I searched and found that its not an error. That's okay but I don't want my app to get minimized when back button is pressed. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove **finish()** from MainActivity. (If you have one at the intent where you call for Game Activity.)

Comment: I did. But I was not sure already if it will help. Now when I press back button from GameOver activity. I am again in the same Game, running infinitely.

Comment: Okay, keep your finish() on Game Activity and see if there is any finish() present in your Main Activity.

If its there then remove it.

Comment: Haha. I didn't notice that I did put finish() at intent at MainActivity. Thanks for the answer. I have modified your answer, accept the edit so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's about requestPermissions handling.
When you will sending many requestPermissions together.