# AlertDialog becomes non responsive?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

We have an [alert dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog) which appears on the activity resume.

Occasionally this dialog doesn't the response to touch/click application appears frozen, But the app is not hanged as the cursor on the edit text on dialog keeps the usual blinking, Only log I can see with repeatedly when such thing happens is below.

```
W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent
```

This doesn't happen all the time but rarely.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: Have to try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161298/android-error-cancelling-event-due-to-no-window-focus

Comment: I searched your error, there are many different results on SO.